# If variable is set, show $_SESSION data

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I have a hard time with isset() function. Exactly how do I tell php that only if the data was assigned to my, lets say $_SESSION['msg']; variable, only then activate it and use it... So far I am getting a lot of notices: undefined index and this code doesn't do it also:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['monster']) &
isset($_SESSION['spol']) &  
isset($_SESSION['combat']) &
isset($_SESSION['turns']) &  
isset($_SESSION['zmaga']) &
isset($_SESSION['zguba']) &
isset($_SESSION['cekini']) &
isset($_SESSION['post']) )

{
$monster = $_SESSION['monster'];
$spol = $_SESSION['spol'];
$combat = $_SESSION['combat'];
$turns = $_SESSION['turns'];
$zmaga = $_SESSION['zmaga'];
$zguba = $_SESSION['zguba'];
$cekini = $_SESSION['cekini'];
$_POST = $_SESSION['post'];
}
```

Data was supposed to be asigned to it from a redirecting previous site but that site doesn't always activate so I need an alternative. That's why I am asking this.

EDIT with full code:

```
session_start();

include 'razno.php';
include 'save.php';
include 'stats.php';

$igralec_ime = $_SESSION['username'];
$monster = prikazi_borba($igralec_ime);
$poskodbe = prikazi_stat('curhp', $igralec_ime);

if (prikazi_stat('curhp', $igralec_ime) == 0)
{
$moznost = 'Tvoje zdravje je resno ogroženo, vrni se domov!';
}

else if (isset($_SESSION['monster']) &&
isset($_SESSION['spol']) &&  
isset($_SESSION['combat']) &&
isset($_SESSION['turns']) &&  
isset($_SESSION['zmaga']) &&
isset($_SESSION['zguba']) &&
isset($_SESSION['cekini']) &&
isset($_SESSION['post']) )
{
$monster = $_SESSION['monster'];
$spol = $_SESSION['spol'];
$combat = $_SESSION['combat'];
$turns = $_SESSION['turns'];
$zmaga = $_SESSION['zmaga'];
$zguba = $_SESSION['zguba'];
$cekini = $_SESSION['cekini'];
$_POST = $_SESSION['post'];

}

update_save($igralec_ime, 'gozd', $monster);

include '../html/gozd.html';
?>
```

Comment: You're using bitwise AND `&` instead of logical AND `&&`.

Comment: Easier still, you can use `if(isset($var1, $var2, $var3, ...))`, which will return `true` if all the variables are set.

Comment: thanks, yea prob should shorten my code. Though problem is still there, I updated my question

Comment: My guess is that you're not setting the variables when the `$_SESSION` indexes are not defined, but you're trying to use them later anyway. For example, you use `$monster` right after the `if`, even though it may not be set.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to replace & with and:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['monster']) and isset($_SESSION['spol']) and isset($_SESSION['combat']) and isset($_SESSION['turns']) and isset($_SESSION['zmaga']) and isset($_SESSION['zguba']) &
isset($_SESSION['cekini']) and isset($_SESSION['post']) )

{
$monster = $_SESSION['monster'];
$spol = $_SESSION['spol'];
$combat = $_SESSION['combat'];
$turns = $_SESSION['turns'];
$zmaga = $_SESSION['zmaga'];
$zguba = $_SESSION['zguba'];
$cekini = $_SESSION['cekini'];
$_POST = $_SESSION['post'];
}
```

Comment: Gents thank you, though still I get "Notice: Undefined variable: spol..." and the variable is invisible like it isn't there at all.Maybe my problem might be elswere? I updated my question with full code

Comment: Is it defined in the files you included (I've had problems with that in the past)? Based on this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830334/how-can-i-see-a-variable-defined-in-another-php-file), you'll need to set those variables as $GLOBALS['var_name']

Comment: I didn't include files I redirected the page to a new page which is now having problems if I use isset() but works without isset(). On my page that redirects they are indeed defined like so "$_SESSION['spol'] = $spol;". Do you know what may be the problem?

Comment: Fixed it, I use "or" instead of "and" because not all variables were defined at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) in PHP. In many programming languages (PHP included) `&` is **'bitwise and'** operator (not logical). Since you want logical operator you need to use `&&` or `and`. Also take a look at other PHP operators, just to get familiar with them and to avoid problems like this.

Also if you are using those values outside the if/then block you should think about cases when your statement will be false and assign some default values to those variables.

Comment: Correction, they just don't want to get set I don't know why